# Point to specific rows of 2-D arrays

Tags: c++, c++11, variable-assignment, addressof

I wrote the following code to point to first row of a 2-dimensional array. However, when I do

```
arrayPtr = & array[0];
```

I end up getting

> error: cannot convert `double (*)[1]` to `double*` in assignment
>
> ```
>  arrayPtr = & array[0];
> ```

My program is:

```
#include <iostream>
    
int main(int argc, char **argv) 
{       
    double array[2][1];

    array[0][1] = 1.0;
    array[1][1] = 2.0;
    
    double* arrayPtr;
    arrayPtr = &array[0];
    
    return 0;
}
```

Can someone help me understand as to where am I going wrong?

Comment: Don't spam tags. This is not C.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `arrayPtr = & array[0]`, you can write

```
 arrayPtr = array[0];
```

to make use of array decay property.

Related,

- Quoting `C11`, chapter §6.3.2.1, *Lvalues, arrays, and function designators*

  > Except when it is the operand of the `sizeof` operator, the `_Alignof` operator, or the
  >   unary `&` operator, or is a string literal used to initialize an array, an expression that has
  >   type *‘‘array of type’’* is converted to an expression with type *‘‘pointer to type’’* that points
  >   to the initial element of the array object and is not an lvalue. [...]
- Quoting `C++14`, chapter §5.3.3

  > The lvalue-to-rvalue `(4.1)`, array-to-pointer `(4.2)`, and function-to-pointer `(4.3)` standard conversions are not
  >   applied to the operand of `sizeof`.

  and, for chapter *4.2*,

  > An lvalue or rvalue of type *“array of N T”* or *“array of unknown bound of T”* can be converted to a prvalue
  >   of type *“pointer to T”*. The result is a pointer to the first element of the array.

So, while used as the RHS operand of the assignment operator, `array[0]` decays to the pointer to the first element of the array, i.e, produces a type `double*` which is the same as the LHS.

Otherwise, the use of `&` operator prevents the array decay for `array[0]` which is an array of type `double [1]`.

Thus, `&array[0]` returns a type which is a pointer to an array of `double [1]`, or, `double (*) [1]` which is not *compatible* with the type of the variable supplied in LHS of the assignment, a `double *`.

Comment: Worked, but why is it so?

Comment: I am sorry, but I still did not understand as to what do you mean by "array decay"

Comment: @AlexanderFell better now?

Comment: simple : array is a double**, array[y] is a double*, array[y][x] is a double. &array[y][x] is a double*, &array[y] is a double** &array is a double***. You want a row so you want a double*. arrayPtr = array[y];

Answer (score 2):

In your code:

- `array` is of type `double (*)[1]`;
- `array[0]` is of type `double[1]`
- `&array[0]` (this equals to `array`) is of type `double (*)[1]` (i.e. pointer to `double[1]`)

**Note 1:** `T[]` can decay to `T*`. So in your example `double[]` can decay to `double *`.

**Note 2:** `a[b]` == `*(a + b)`, so in your example `&array[0]` equals to `& (*(array + 0))` which is simplified to `array` itself.

Answer (score 1):

```
double array[2][1];
double* arrayPtr;
arrayPtr = & array[0];
```

`arrayPtr` has the type

```
POINTER (DOUBLE)
```

while `array` has the type

```
POINTER(POINTER(DOUBLE))
```

`&array[0]` has the type

```
POINTER(POINTER(DOUBLE))
```

You try to assign

```
POINTER (DOUBLE) <= POINTER(POINTER(DOUBLE))
```

The correct way to do it is

```
arrayPtr = array[0];
```

or

```
arrayPtr = *array;
```

Comment: your second and third option are wrong as they are not equivalent to the first. Maybe you mean `arrayPtr = *array` ?